# How to display the lower part of an image in an ImageView 'shaped' as a banner

Tags: android, android-imageview

Let's say I have a 512x512 Image.
I want to display a banner at the bottom of my screen which shows the bottom of this image. It has to use the whole width of the screen and respect the ration aspect.

The problem is that I'm always failing in displaying the bottom of my main image. What I see is the center of my image...

```
      <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/myImage"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: `How to display the lower part of an image in a banner` ? Think you mean: `How to display the lower part of an image in an ImageView`.

Comment: yes in an ImageView 'shaped' as a banner, meaning full width but small height

Comment: if you are no concerned with upper part...why not to crop an image and use it

Comment: I just want to know how to display the lower part of the image. Please give more detail if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. Please supply a list of all possibilities. Something with bottom?

Comment: the 'scaleType' parameter doesn't change anything.